# Why is my writeStream function writing only one line?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have been struggling to understand this weird Spark stream behaviour.

I want to write 2 files of CSV into a delta table using a Spark Streaming.

I made this example only to understand how Streams work, I dont want to use other solutions I just need to understand why is this not working.

So, I have to CSV files in `/test/input`:

```
A.csv
+---+---+
| id|  x|
+---+---+
|  1|  A|
|  2|  B|
|  3|  C|
+---+---+

B.csv
+---+---+
| id|  x|
+---+---+
|  4|  D|
|  5|  E|
+---+---+
```

I read the directory (so the union of the two dataframes above) as a stream:

```
schema = StructType([StructField("id",IntegerType(),True), StructField("x",StringType(),True)])                

df = spark.readStream.format("csv").schema(schema).option("ignoreChanges", "true").option("delimiter", ";").option("header", True).load("/test/input")
```

I then wanted to write this stream using the following code:

```
def processDf(df, epoch_id):
  Ids=[x.id for x in df.select("id").distinct().collect()]
  for i in Ids:
    temp_df=df.filter((df.id==i))
    temp_df.write.format("delta").option("mergeSchema", "true").partitionBy("id").option("replaceWhere", "id=="+str(i)).mode("append").save("/test/res")
  
  
df.writeStream.format("delta").foreachBatch(processDf).queryName("x").option("checkpointLocation", "/test/check").trigger(once=True).start()
```

No errors are shown. The code executes successfully.
When I go to check my files in /test/res I find all data:

[image]

But when I check delta data, I notice that only the first line is present:

```
df= (spark.read.format("delta").option("sep", ";").option("header", "true").load("/test/res")).cache()

+---+---+
| id|  x|
+---+---+
|  1|  A|
+---+---+
```

Why isnt it inserting all lines ? Is it the `replaceWhere` option ?
replaceWhere is supposed to delete only the partitions that are already in the table and got updated in source data.

What am I doing wrong please.

**EDIT:**

Same behaviour is noticed even if I read only one CSV in input. Code still writes only one line in output instead of all lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a syntaxical error, I changed the loop block with the following and it worked:

```
for i in ids:
    i=str(i)
    tmp = df.filter(df.id == i)
    tmp.write.format("delta").option("mergeSchema", "true").partitionBy(PartitionKey).option("replaceWhere", "id == '$i'".format(i=i)).save("/res/")
```